# Read multiple files with for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, data-processing

My code is below. In the code, I am evaluating only the data in the `'fb2010'` file. I want to add other files" `'fb2020'`, `'fb2030'`, and `'fb2040'` and evaluate their data by the same code. My question is how to apply a `for` loop and include the other data files. I tried, but I got confused by the `for` loop.

```
load('fb2010');                                    % loading the data
x = fb2010(3:1:1502,:);
% y_filt = filter(b,a,x);                          % filtering the received signal
y_filt= filter(b,a,x,[],2);
%%%%%%%  fourier transform
nfft = length(y_filt);
res = fft(y_filt,nfft,2)/nfft;
res2 = res(:,1:nfft/2+1);                           %%%% taking single sided spectrum
res3 = fft(res2,[],2);
for i = 3:1:1500                                   %%%% dividing each row by first row.
 resd(i,:) = res3(i,:)./res3(1,:);
end
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, i have not mentioned language. Its Matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your files are MAT-files, not ASCII. You can do this by having [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) return a [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) and using [dynamic field referencing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/):

```
n = 4;
for i = 1:n
    vname = ['fb20' int2str(i) '0']; % Create file/variable name based on index
    s = load(vname);                 % Load data as struct (overwriting previous s)
    x = s.(vname)(3:1:1502,:);       % Access struct with dynamic field reference

    % Rest of your code
    ...
end
```

If you're using a plain ASCII file, `load` won't produce a struct. However, such files are much simpler (see documentation for `load`/`save`). The following code would probably work:

```
n = 4;
for i = 1:n
    vname = ['fb20' int2str(i) '0']; % Create file/variable name based on index
    s = load(vname);                 % Load data as matrix (overwriting previous s)
    x = s(3:1:1502,:);               % Directly index matrix

    % Rest of your code
    ...
end
```

It would be a good idea to add the file extension to your `load` command to make your code more readable.

Comment: Hey Horchler, I want to have a matrix for each data set. Then how shoud i apply. now I am getting only one metrix resd.?